# How to remove the different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames df1 and df2:

```
>>df1 
 Index X Y
   1   1 3
   2   2 4
   3   3 5
   4   4 6
>>df2
 Index
   2
   4
```

I want something like:

```
>>df3
 Index X Y
  2   2 4 
  4   4 6
```

How could I remove all the rows with different Index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if `Index` is a column of `df1` and `df2` or the actual index. If it's a column like `X` or `Y` then the following will work

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'X': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [2, 4]})

df3 = df1.loc[df1.Index.isin(df2.Index)]
```

If it's the actual table index then the following will work

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'X': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y': [3, 4, 5, 6]},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4], 
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={},
    index=[2, 4],
)

df3 = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've changed the question that I want to keep the Index [2,4] and remove the rows with index [1,3]